# Как сделать кроссбраузерные размеры текста?

Tags: css3, html5

Заголовки и абзацы в хроме и мозиле отличаются. Как сделать размер шрифта одинаковым в двух браузерах. Пытался добавлять префиксы -moz-  -webkit- не помогает

Comment: Прописываете определенный font-size и всё. Разная отрисовка шрифтов браузерами - не ваша проблема, т.к. вы никак не можете на это повлиять.

Comment: В продолжение цикла вредные советы или для тех кто не ищет легких путей, как в 90х: сделайте картинки. Например svg-path'ами

Answer (score 1):

Просто явно задайте размер шрифта для ваших заголовков с помощью свойства `font-size`

У разных браузеров разные стили по-умолчанию, это касается размеров шрифтов, отступов, цветов и т.п.

Вообще хорошая практика сбрасывать стили браузера, просто подключить к проекту файл `reset.css`, например вот с такими стилями:

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}ol,ul{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;*font-size:100%}
```

Стили представлены в минимизированом виде, просто скопируйте и вставьте в свой проект как вам будет удобнее

Таким образом ваши сайты будут приведены к некому единообразию, будет меньше вот таких вот проблем со шрифтами и т.п.

Comment: Лучше уж использовать Normalize.css: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ Сейчас это «типовая» практика.